How to access SSH of AWS EC2 Instance(ubuntu) without pem file
I tried a solution but that doesn't work.

Login into your instance with the .pem file
cd / (just incase)
Edit, vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config and edit
PasswordAuthentication yes
Restart sshd service, service sshd restart or systemctl restart sshd or equivilent
Set password, passwd - (user : ubuntu)
Log out and log back in without .pem file ssh root@{public IP}

After then, I tried ssh ubuntu@{public IP} , I got ubuntu@{public IP}: Permission denied (publickey) and I checked a debug too
...
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\{User}/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\{User}/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ubuntu@{public IP}: Permission denied (publickey)

I couldn't access. I think it's still find pem file.
So How could I access without pem file?

Try to ask this on https://askubuntu.com/

how did that comment and closing helped OP at all @stdunbar ?
This is what i hate about old-school 'forums'... "use search" they say all over the place... good luck finding an answer.

Look for files in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/: they will override the base config. You should also check ~ubuntu/.ssh/config in case there are user-specific overrides. As well as the config on your client. (I haven't looked, so this is not an answer, but I've seen it in the past).

@bua - I didn't say use search.  I said that the OP should ask an Ubuntu administrative question in an Ubuntu forum as SO is a programming forum.

@kdgregory don't mislead OP.... i gave him correct answer already

Looks like you don't have your local PC keypair needed for ssh handshake.
Try to generate it on your PC, and login again:
ssh-keygen -o


Where are you proposing the OP run ssh-keygen? If it's on local Windows PC then wouldn't this simply create a local private/public keypair, unrelated to the Ubuntu EC2 instance?

@jarmod yes, I clearly stated to generate rsa keypair on his PC.  ssh (TLS) still needs to  encrypt the channel before connecting to EC2.  For that id_rsa (default name) key's is needed.

And copy the generated public key to the Ubuntu system.

No need to copy. OP didn't ask for this specifically.  Fixing above gives him password access (solving his initial question). Adding public key to EC2 'authorized_keys` is potentially an optional next step which OP didn't ask for

The SSH transport layer is independent of the user's private/public key.

@kdgregory what you talking about ? SSH is not a transport layer...  SSH uses rsa keypair to establish secure connection to sshd server

Transport as in RFC4253 SSH Transport Layer Protocol

@kdgregory again, what's your point ?  OP is missing rsa keypairs in home directory....
Also, the document you referenced, clearly states that:
"Key exchange method, public key algorithm, symmetric encryption algorithm...." - so you saying SSH it's independed from priv/pub keypair... is wroing.

Thank you for you guys helps. I solved it. first I generated ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my_email@example.com". then I copied the generated key to the Ubuntu EC2 instance.
